# print or select inside SQLServer function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In SQLServer sometimes following the code without debugging is necessary. It is possible with `print` statement or with `select` statement. The problem is SQLServer does not allow these methods within the functions. That makes the complex function like the black box. I have tried to use write the messages to the text file with stored procedure within the function, however, it doesn't allow either.

Is there any way to track my code like `print` statement within the function.

Comment: Why don't you use a logging table and simply write whatever output you want into that?

Comment: @SchmitzIT - not valid in functions either

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

> The problem is SQLServer does not allow these methods within the functions

is the problem and the answer at the same time. Yes: This is not allowed within functions.

When I've to deal with larger function code, I usually copy this code into a query window and test it externally. Doing so, you can use `PRINT` or `SELECT ...  INTO` or any other approach to save some intermediate values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I am doing same. I debugging function externally, however, there are hundreds of old spaghetti-coded functions in the project I deal with and this way is not practical for me.  I cannot understand this kind of unnecessary obstacles in SQLServer.

Comment: An alternative to PRINT is RAISERROR ('a message', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT which sends the output to the screen immediately. [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1660/using-the-nowait-option-with-the-sql-server-raiserror-statement/)